# ListView ghosting when using DrawerLayout with Fragments

Tags: android, android-listview

My layout was working fine before I switched it to use fragments inside the DrawerLayout. After that the ListView in the main view ghosts a copy of the list when scrolling.

The ListView contents scroll, but a copy of the first page remains on screen. I've been logging debug messages and there is no second copy of listview created, and no second copy of data sent from the adapter.

[image]

The layout for the activity uses DrawerLayout with fragments before switching to fragments it worked fine.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="400dp"
    android:layout_height="800dp">

<!-- The main content view -->
<fragment android:name="com.nosweatbudgets.receipts.ReceiptsFragment"
          android:id="@+id/receipts_fragment"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />

<!-- The navigation drawer -->
<fragment android:name="com.nosweatbudgets.navigate.NavigateFragment"
          android:id="@+id/navigate_fragment"
          android:layout_width="300dp"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:layout_gravity="start"
        />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

The fragment classes are each very simple.

ReceiptsFragment's onCreateView looks like this.

```
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.receipts, container, false);

    _adapter = new ReceiptsAdapter(inflater);
    ListView list = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.receipt_list);
    list.setAdapter(_adapter);
    _adapter.Refresh();

    return view;
```

NavigateFragment's onCreateView is basically the same with a different adapter. It's the ReceiptsFragment that is ghosting while the NavigateFragment does not ghost. Yet they can basically the same approach.

```
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.navigate, container, false);

    _navigate = new NavigateAdapter(inflater);
    // setup the list view for the side
    ListView list = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
    list.setAdapter(_navigate);
    _navigate.Refresh();

    return view;
```

For the above fragment classes I'm using the following layouts.

`receipts.xml` looks like this.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    >
<ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/receipt_list"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

`navigate.xml` looks like this.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    >
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:background="#EEEEEE"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The pull out navigate listview works just fine, but the main receipts listview has the ghosting problem.

I'm completely stumped as to what is causing this.

**EDIT**:

Here is how views are created in the `ReceiptsAdapter`.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    View view = convertView;
    if (view == null)
    {
        view = _inflater.inflate(R.layout.receipt, null);
    }

    TextView txt_vendor = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.receipt_vendor);
    TextView txt_category = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.receipt_category);
    TextView category_btn = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.category_btn);

    Model receipt = _receipts.get(position);

    int vendor_id = receipt.getAsInteger("smart_vendor_id");
    int category_id = receipt.getAsInteger("smart_category_id");


    if (_vendors.indexOfKey(vendor_id) >= 0)
    {
        txt_vendor.setText(_vendors.get(vendor_id));
    }
    else
    {
        txt_vendor.setText("Select Vendor");
    }

    if (_categories.indexOfKey(category_id) >= 0)
    {
        String cat = _categories.get(category_id);
        txt_category.setText(cat);
        category_btn.setText(Category.ShortTitle(cat));
        category_btn.setBackgroundColor(Category.Color(cat));
        //txt_category.setBackgroundColor(c);
    }
    else
    {
        txt_category.setText("Select Category");
        category_btn.setText("N/A");
    }

    ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.receipt_amount)).setText("$" + receipt.getAsString("amount"));
    ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.receipt_payment)).setText(receipt.getAsString("payment"));
    ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.receipt_date)).setText(receipt.getAsString("receipt_date"));

    return view;
}
```

**EDIT**:

This is how the Activity for the layout attaches the fragments via the `onCreate` method.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // the layout uses fixed width/size, because the layout editor won't render match_parent.
    // so I replace the layout parameters here with match_parent.
    DrawerLayout layout = (DrawerLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.main, null);
    DrawerLayout.LayoutParams param = new DrawerLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams
            .MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    layout.setLayoutParams(param);
    setContentView(layout);

    // configure this activity
    StyleActionBar();

    // Add the fragments
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.navigate_fragment, new NavigateFragment())
            .add(R.id.receipts_fragment, new ReceiptsFragment())
            .commit();
}
```

Comment: Just to confirm that I understand you correctly: when you tap to open the drawer, you see the `NavigateFragment` layered on top of the `ReceiptsFragment`? But when the drawer is closed (before opening the drawer or after closing it), you just see `ReceiptsFragment`?

Comment: can we see the getView method from the adapter? also the Refresh one if possible.

Comment: @CommonsWare hi ware, You are correct. NavigateFragment is the hidden view you slide out from the left, and ReceiptsFragment is the main view that is always visible.

Comment: @NeronT I added the getView to the question. The `Refresh` method calls an JSON service to create an `ArrayList` of receipt records. Both navigate and receipts use the same underlying JSON code, but navigate doesn't ghost so I don't think that is the problem.

Comment: You might try switching `NavigateFragment` to be a dynamic fragment, created via a `FragmentTransaction`. A static fragment via the `<fragment>` tag is supposed to always be there, and it's possible that the "always be there" part is fouling up the `DrawerLayout` logic.

Comment: @CommonsWare Interesting I'll give that a try.

Comment: @CommonsWare oh, I figured it out. You sent me in the right direction. I'll post my answer. Thanks ware.

Comment: Thanks for asking this question. Having a similar issue on a project that I am working on as well but it is not always repeatable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I mistakenly followed the fragments tutorial incorrectly, and created both a static fragment in the layout XML and also created a dynamic fragment for the same class at run-time.

The main layout used the `<fragment>` tag to create a fragment which is automatically attached at runtime via the `android:name` property.

This is what I have in my `layout.xml`

```
<fragment android:name="com.nosweatbudgets.receipts.ReceiptsFragment"
          android:id="@+id/receipts_fragment"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />
```

That was enough to create the fragment, but I mistakenly added code from the fragments tutorial in my activity as follows.

```
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.navigate_fragment, new NavigateFragment())
            .add(R.id.receipts_fragment, new ReceiptsFragment())
            .commit();
```

That added two additional fragment views to the activity at runtime. This resulted in two listviews for the same position.

What appeared to be a ghosting artifact was infact two fragments for the same class on top of each other. Removing the dynamic creation in `onCreate` resolved my problem.

Comment: This just further validates the centuries-old rule for carpentry: "Measure twice. Instantiate fragments once." Or something like that... :-)

Comment: @cgTag Five years later and I did the same thing...thanks.